# How are Y-dwarf spectral subtypes defined?

Tags: brown-dwarf, classification, spectral-type

It is often stated that the spectral subtype indicates the relative position between spectral types, e.g. G5 being halfway from the start of spectral type G to the beginning of spectral type F.

Given that we haven't observed a spectral type cooler than Y, how can subtypes Y0, Y1, Y2 be defined?

Comment: Spectral class Y is also used on sub-brown dwarfs. Sub-brown dwarfs don't have enough mass to ignite Deuterium. An example for such Y-type body is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WD_0806%E2%88%92661

Comment: @Greenhorn - this is a question about spectral types, i.e. the classification of *spectra*, not about how to define "sub-brown dwarfs".